# WhatsApp Web creates zip when sending .apk file

Tags: android, file, zip, apk, whatsapp

I am trying to send .apk file through WhatsApp Web but eventually it gets converted to zip file at recipient end(android phone)

Is there a way to avoid this conversion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue I saw when sending apk file in Safari whatsapp web. In chrome it works fine

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with WhatsApp. Use google drive to upload the APK on the computer and then install it on your phone by using the google drive app.